# What is the correct syntax for the IF function?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to make a cell output "Some words" if the number cell in `B10` in a page named "Page" is greater than or equal to 3. If not, it should output "Some other words".

I tried `=IF("'PAGE'!B10≤3", "Some Words", "Some other words")`, but I got an error saying it's not a number. How do I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the quotation marks in/around your expression:

```
=IF(PAGE!B10 <= 3, "Some words", "Some other words")
```

The `IF` function takes a boolean expression as its first parameter. In your formula, you are passing it a string (because of the quotation marks).

Comment: It also doesn't support the ≤ sign.